# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on custom UIView class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've made a custom view class. I'm initializing it in my view controller class. I've enabled user interaction then also it's not working. I've searched it in similar questions but most of them say to enable user interaction.
Here's the code I've written.

```
@interface ProfileCreatorViewController (){

SectionTitleView *ProfileTitle;
CGRect mainFrame;

}

@end

@implementation ProfileCreatorViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    mainFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + NAVBAR_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    CGRect profileFrame = CGRectMake(mainFrame.origin.x + 5, mainFrame.origin.y, mainFrame.size.width - 20, 50);
    ProfileTitle = [[SectionTitleView alloc]initWithFrame:profileFrame withTitle:@"Profile" withUnderLineColor:[UIColor blackColor] withDownButton:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightArrow"]];
    [self.view addSubview:ProfileTitle];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(downButtonClicked)];
    [ProfileTitle addGestureRecognizer:recog];
    ProfileTitle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}


-(void) downButtonClicked{

    NSLog(@"clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check couple of things here 
profileFrame's height and width are not very small (print profileFrame)

ProfileTitle is not complete transparent (Gesture will also not work when view's alpha is very close to 0)

ProfileTitle is not obscured by any other view (use visual debugger for that)

Comment: complete transparent view was the culprit, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface ProfileCreatorViewController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

SectionTitleView *ProfileTitle;
CGRect mainFrame;

}

@end

@implementation ProfileCreatorViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    mainFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + NAVBAR_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    CGRect profileFrame = CGRectMake(mainFrame.origin.x + 5, mainFrame.origin.y, mainFrame.size.width - 20, 0);
    ProfileTitle = [[SectionTitleView alloc]initWithFrame:profileFrame withTitle:@"Profile" withUnderLineColor:[UIColor blackColor] withDownButton:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightArrow"]];
    [self.view addSubview:ProfileTitle];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(downButtonClicked:)];
    recog.delegate=self;
    [ProfileTitle addGestureRecognizer:recog];
    ProfileTitle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}


-(void) downButtonClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{

    NSLog(@"clicked");
}
```

Add a delegate and change your method signature

Comment: Nope, still not woking. Thanks, though.

Comment: `NSLog` youe view check whether the view is assigned to tap gesture or not

Answer (score 2):

Try these..

create property of your custom view like these..and also import it in your ProfileCreatorViewController.h file like these..

```
#import "SectionTitleView.h"

@property (nonatomic , strong) SectionTitleView *previewView;
```

**Add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**

```
@interface ProfileCreatorViewController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
   SectionTitleView *ProfileTitle;
   CGRect mainFrame;
}
```

**set NumberOfTapsRequired if you want**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recog = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(downButtonClicked:)];     
ProfileTitle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[recog setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];  //No. of taps..
[ProfileTitle addGestureRecognizer:recog];
```

**and also its method**

```
-(void) downButtonClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"Taped");
}
```

i hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You need the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` inside the header file.
Also create a `property` to hold the `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture;
```

You also shouldn't create the `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside the parent class. The **ProfileTitle** should generate this by itself. So you'd better insert the code inside `viewDidLoad` inside **SectionTitleView**.

**FYI:** And don't use capitalized variable names