# UITapGestureRecognizer not working with custom view class

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

`UITapGestureRecognizer` works perfectly fine in **code 1**. `tapAction` is called as expected.
However it's not working in **code 2**. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong in **code 2**?

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043832/subview-gesture-recognizer-not-being-called) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449919/uitapgesturerecognizer-not-working-on-custom-uiview-class) are quite similar questions, but still couldn't figure it out)

**Code 1:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        myView.backgroundColor = .red
        myView.addGestureRecognizer( UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(self.tapAction)) )

        self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }

    @objc func tapAction() {
        print("tapped")
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myView = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }
}

class MyView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func initView(){
        let myView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        myView.backgroundColor = .red
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(self.doSomethingOnTap)))
        addSubview(myView)
    }

    @objc func doSomethingOnTap() {
        print("tapped")
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, the origin for 'myView' inside the 'initView' method should be (x: 0, y: 0) not (x: 100, y: 100). (Although adding a subview inside the UIView seems unnecessary anyway - why not just add the gesture recognizer to 'self'?)

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeck Yes, you are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a subview that in this particular case goes out of the parent bounds because the view main view has 100 height and 100 width and the subview is placed at x: 100 and y: 100, resulting to be positioned at the exact end of the parent.

The subview you create in `initView` should have `(x: 0, y: 0)` origin.